Question regarding property of greatest integer function
In my textbooks section about the properties of the greatest integer function the two following properties looked quite interesting and i could not understand them right away.
Property 1
$$\lfloor(\frac{x}{n})\rfloor + \lfloor(\frac{x+1}{n})\rfloor + \lfloor(\frac{x+2}{n})\rfloor + \ldots + \lfloor(\frac{x + n-1}{n})\rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor\hspace{10mm}n \in N$$
Property 2
$$\lfloor(x)\rfloor + \lfloor(x + \frac{1}{n})\rfloor + \lfloor(x + \frac{2}{n})\rfloor + \ldots + \lfloor(x + \frac{n-1}{n})\rfloor = \lfloor(nx)\rfloor$$
I could not understand how these sum's work and how to understand them, they might be converging sums but how.
Could someone give me a explanation behind these properties?
Any help would be appreciated!

I had a proof for this somewhere here. I'll try to find it.

Property 1 follows from Property 2 by replacing $x$ by $\frac xn$.
Property 2:  Any real number $x$ can be written as
$$ x = m + \frac rn + s$$
where $m$ is an integer, $r = 0,1,\dots,n-1$, and $0\le s< \frac1n$.
Then for $k=0,1,\dots,n-1$, we have
$$\lfloor x + \frac kn\rfloor= \begin{cases} m & \text{if $k < n-r$} \\
m+1 & \text{if $k \ge n-r$}. \end{cases}$$
So the left hand side is $mn + r$, and this happens to be the same as $\lfloor nx \rfloor$.

Let the property $2$ be noted $(**)$
$$\lfloor x\rfloor + \left\lfloor x + \frac{1}{n}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor x + \frac{2}{n}\right\rfloor + \ldots + \left\lfloor x + \frac{n-1}{n}\right\rfloor = \lfloor nx\rfloor\hspace 1.cm (**)$$ let as usual $x=\lfloor x\rfloor+\{x\}$
►When $\{x\}+\dfrac{n-1}{n}\lt1\iff n\{x\}\lt1$ so $(**)$ becomes
$$\underbrace{\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor x\rfloor+\cdots+\lfloor x\rfloor}_{n\space times}=n\lfloor x\rfloor$$ but
$\lfloor nx\rfloor=\lfloor n(\lfloor x\rfloor+\{x\})\rfloor=\lfloor n\lfloor x\rfloor+n\{x\}\rfloor=n\lfloor x\rfloor$ because $ n\{x\}\lt1$
►► Let the smallest $k$ such that $1\le k\le n-1$ so $1\lt \{x\}+\dfrac kn\iff \boxed{n-k\lt n\{x\}}$.
Now $(**)$ becomes
$$\underbrace{\lfloor x\rfloor+\cdots+\lfloor x\rfloor}_{k\space times}+\underbrace{(\lfloor x\rfloor+1)+\cdots+(\lfloor x\rfloor+1)}_{n-k\space times}=n\lfloor x\rfloor+n-k$$ Since $n-k\lt n\{x\}$ we have $$n\lfloor x\rfloor+n-k=\lfloor nx\rfloor$$ similar to the precedent case noted ►.
Property $1$  come from  property $2$ putting $\dfrac xn$ instead of $x$.
